# Send Complex MIME Emails

Tags: php, openssl, content-management-system, mime, smime

I have been told to send an email with attachement. The attachement is a MIME object. The MIME object should be formed as in the picture.

[image]

The object `Atto.msg` is composed by some signed pieces (those in green) and some additional info, like `IndiceBusta.xml`. 
Than, the Atto.msg should be crypted in `PKCS#7` with a session key and by adding additional info like IssuerDName and SerialNumber.

Now, supposing I am on a LAMP server, my question is:

how can I make a MIME object containing several parts? I know how to sign `DatiAtto.xml` and `CorpoAtto.pdf`, but I do not know how to add the other info in the white box and then may the final crypting process... I do not event know how to add The Session Key (Chiave Sessione)...
The document says that the structure of the info should be CadEs.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Assuming you have each part in MIME format, a multiplart MIME begins with: Content-Type: multipart/mixed; followed by a unique boundary string that separates all the parts. The last boundary string at the bottom is followed by --

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if there is something ready-to-use in php?